# error SessionMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

I am trying to store my HashMap value in session and then I am retrieving it using JSP but I am receiving an error saying

> HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Any idea why I am getting that error?

```
package com.action;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import com.action.GetCon;




public class JanuaryAction implements SessionAware{
private String name;
Map abc = new HashMap();


public Map getAbc() {
return abc;
}

public void setAbc(Map abc) {
this.abc = abc;
}


public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void setSession(Map abc) {
this.abc = (HashMap) abc;

}
public String execute() throws Exception{

String time=getName();
 /*   System.out.println(time);*/
if(time.equals("January 2013")){

abc.put(time,"'2013-01-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-01-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("February 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-02-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("March 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-03-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-03-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("April 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-04-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-04-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("May 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-05-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-05-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("June 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-06-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-06-05'" );
}
String newtime=(String)abc.get(time);
   /* System.out.println(newtime);*/

Connection con = GetCon.getCon();
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2),  COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >=" +newtime+ " GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ;
Object value = abc.remove(time);

while(resultset.next()){

String marketplace = resultset.getString(1);

String orderdate = resultset.getString(2);

Double datamount = resultset.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset.getInt(4);

Double result=resultset.getDouble(5);

abc.put(0, marketplace);
abc.put(1, orderdate);
abc.put(2, datamount);
abc.put(3, count);
abc.put(4, result);}

return "success";
}}
```

In my JSP, I wanted to display the loop values one by one. so i am using this code now, but it is not displaying anything.

```
<s:property value="#session.0" /><br><br><br>
<s:property value="#session.1" /><br><br><br>
<s:property value="#session.2" /><br><br><br>
<s:property value="#session.3" /><br><br><br>
<s:property value="#session.4" /><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `SessionAware` implementation, use it

```
private Map<String, Object> session;

@Override
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
 this.session = session;
}
```

in the `execute` create a new collection with values and put into the session map.
The problem with your code you are reusing the same variable `abc` that initially used to build the query. You should create another one and use the `List` instead of `Map` to keep the order of the items you want to iterate and display in JSP. Better to create and use the class that you should populate from the `ResultSet` and populate it into the list.

```
public class Market {
  private String marketplace;  
  private String orderdate;  
  private Double datamount;
  private Integer count;  
  private Double result;

  public String getMarketplace() {
    return marketplace;
  }

  public void setMarketplace(String marketplace) {
    this.marketplace = marketplace;
  }

  public String getOrderdate() {
    return orderdate;
  }

  public void setOrderdate(String orderdate) {
    this.orderdate = orderdate;
  }

  public Double getDatamount() {
    return datamount;
  }

  public void setDatamount(Double datamount) {
    this.datamount = datamount;
  }

  public Integer getCount() {
    return count;
  }

  public void setCount(Integer count) {
    this.count = count;
  }

  public Double getResult() {
    return result;
  }

  public void setResult(Double result) {
    this.result = result;
  }

  public Market(String marketplace, String orderdate, Double datamount, Integer count, Double result) {
    this.marketplace = marketplace;
    this.orderdate = orderdate;
    this.datamount = datamount;
    this.count = count;
    this.result = result;
  }

}
```

create the property to hold the results

```
@Element(value = Market.class)
private List<Market> markets = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Market> getMarkets() {
  return markets;
}

public void setMarkets(List<Market> markets) {
  this.markets = markets;
}
```

to populate the list you should use this block, I don't know how do you use the connection, so I didn't close it.

```
Connection con = GetCon.getCon();
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
try {
  ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2),  COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >=" +newtime+ " GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ;
  while(resultset.next()){
  markets.add(new Market(
    resultset.getString(1),
    resultset.getString(2),
    resultset.getDouble(3),
    resultset.getInt(4),
    resultset.getDouble(5)
  ));
  }
} finally {
  try {
    statement.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {}
}
```

}

now to keep the results in session

```
session.put("markets", markets);
```

in the JSP use the `iterator` tag, and you are not required to iterate the session object, just get it from action.

```
<s:iterator value="markets">
  Marketplace: <s:property value="marketplace" /><br> 
  Orderdate: <s:property value="orderdate" /><br>  
  Datamount: <s:property value="datamount" /><br>
  Count: <s:property value="count" /><br>  
  Result: <s:property value="result" /><br>
  <hr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: `session.put(abc, "abc");` should be `session.put("abc", abc);`

Comment: Thank you for the reply but how do i retrieve the values in jsp. I need to retrieve all the 5 values in loop because, because values are taking from database.

Comment: @user2482323 In the JSP to loop over a values that are in the Map use the iterator tag, inside it there's a key and value property that you could use to display the contents of the map. You need struts taglib included in the JSP to use the struts tags.

Comment: Sorry, your answer looks right but little bit confusing,,can you rewrite the code for me please

Comment: @user2482323 What do you want I rewrite for you? Your code is mess of JDBC and action logic. You didn't provide any configuration, nor JSP to let me know what do you want to view. As far as I see you accepted the answer that teach you to distinguish between classes and interfaces. My answer resolves it in the first two statements. Sorry, that you can't understand it.

Comment: sorry, i corrected, actually i thought i clicked on your answer..it was my mistake..wait i will update my code.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is here:

```
@Override
public void setSession(Map abc) {
  //abc is actually a SessionMap, which is not a HashMap !
  this.abc = (HashMap) abc;
}
```

because you suppose that `abc` is an `HashMap`, which is wrong. It is actually a `SessionMap` (that's what the error message says). `SessionMap` does not extends `HashMap`, it extends `AbstractMap` which directly extends `Object`.

See :http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/SessionMap.html

Basically, when you `implements SessionAware` you suppose that the `Map` will be an `HashMap`, which is absolutely not guaranteed and is indeed not the case.

I suggest you to replace the attribute definition :

```
HashMap abc = new HashMap();
```

With:

```
private Map abc; //Don't initialize it as it is done by the setter.
```

Comment: A map is a map, think of the declaration as: GeneralCategoryOfThing NameOfThing = SpecificTypeOfThing(parameters), so like adenoyelle says Map myMap = SomeMap.  Then you can do map like things to it.  HashMap is a particular implementation of map, usually you don't care too much about the specific type of map something is handing you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but how do i retrieve the values in jsp. I need to retrieve all the 5 values in loop because, because values are taking from database.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
@Override
public void setSession(Map abc) {
    this.abc = (HashMap) abc;
}
```

You are casting a `Map` which is an interface to `HashMap`, a concrete implementation. This cast is unsafe since you don't know for sure which type the `abc` is. It can be any of `SessionMap`, `TreeMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, etc.

Since the `setSession` has been defined to take a `Map`, so you should either use that `Map` or create a new one.

```
public class JanuaryAction implements SessionAware{
    private String name;
    Map abc = new HashMap(); // Use the interface Map instead of a concrete implementation

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map abc) {
        // this.abc = abc; // you can do this
        this.abc = new HashMap(abc); // prefer to do this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but how do i retrieve the values in jsp. I need to retrieve all the 5 values in loop because, because values are taking from database.